# Obtain JWT from bubble.io

Tags: jwt, jitsi, bubble.io

I’m trying to generate a JSON Web Token to connect to the private version of jitsi:

https://jaas.8x8.vc/

Since this has to be done from a bubble.io app, is there a service or a way I can send a header, body and key to an API (store the private key there) and get a signed JWT?

Answer (score 1):

Looking briefly at the requirement, I think using the [API Connector](https://manual.bubble.io/core-resources/bubble-made-plugins/api-connector) should do the trick.

You can pass in all the parameters in the spec and return back the JWT token.

Here is an example of a similar generate JWT using the API Connector.

[image: Bubble API Connector]

Here is a longer example of generating a [JWT in Bubble.io](https://docs.ayrshare.com/packages/bubble.io#generate-jwt-token-in-bubble) - using Ayrshare.